# How to create a child object of a has_one association with FactoryGirl and Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have browsed google and stackoverflow for my question and have found some similar ones, but none that solve my problem.

In my app a User has_one Profile and a Profile belongs_to User.

I am trying to test some User features, and I need to create a test Profile associated with my test User to properly do so.

Here is my factories/user_factory.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

  factory :user do 

    email {Faker::Internet.safe_email}
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"

  end

end
```

Here is my factories/profile_factory.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

  factory :profile do 

    phone Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    college Faker::University.name
    hometown Faker::Address.city
    current_location Faker::Address.city
    about "This is an about me"
    words_to_live_by "These are words to live by"
    first_name {Faker::Name.name}
    last_name {Faker::Name.name}
    gender ["male", "female"].sample
    user


  end


end
```

Here is my features/users_spec.rb where I need to create my associated profile:

```
require 'rails_helper'



feature "User accounts" do 

  before do 
    visit root_path
  end

  let(:user) {create(:user)}
  let(:profile) {create(:profile, user: user)}

  scenario "create a new user" do 
    fill_in "firstName", with: "First"
    fill_in "lastName", with: "Last"
    fill_in "signup-email", with: "email@email.com"
    fill_in "signup-password", with: "superpassword"
    fill_in "signup-password-confirm", with: "superpassword"
    #skip birthday=>fill_in "birthday", with: 
    #skip gender
    expect{ click_button "Sign Up!"}.to change(User, :count).by(1)


  end

  scenario "sign in an existing user" do




    sign_in(user)
    expect(page).to have_content "Signed in successfully"
  end

  scenario "a user that is not signed in can not view anything besides the homepage" do 


  end


end #user accounts
```

The scenario sign in an existing user is where I need my associated profile.

Right now I am just creating a profile using the factory

```
let(:profile) {create(:profile, user: user)}
```

I have tried passing the create  block to associate the profile, and I've tried overriding the user_id attribute of the profile to associate it with the created user, but neither have worked.  Ideally I would like to set it up so that whenever a user is created an associated profile is created for it.  Any ideas?

I know this can't be too hard I just haven't been able to come up with a solution.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a factory with the same name as the association. In your case, if the association is *profile*, and you can implicitly create the associated profile record along with the user record. Just use the name of the associated factory, like this.

```
factory :user do
   ...
  profile
end
```

If you need more control, Factory Girl's **association** is what you need. You can override attributes and select a factory name different form the association name. Here, the association name is *prof* and the factory is *profile*. The *lastName* field is overridden.

```
factory :user do
    ...
  association :prof, factory: :profile, lastName: "Johnson"
end
```

You can find more info at Factory Girl's [Getting Started](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md).

Comment: I believe this solves my problem but now I am getting a stack level too deep error pointing to this line in my user_factory:  email {Faker::Internet.safe_email} any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Ah. Your example above has the profile creating a user as part of the factory. I'd suggest removing the *user* line from the Profile factory and let the association be created in the User factory.